# jQuery calendar pagination limits

Tags: jquery

I have an `input` type `date` that is using jQuery datepicker. And from the documentation is possible to see that the year range is by default is: `c-10:c+10` which will show the past 10 years and the future 10 years of the current selected date.

The problem is I do not want this to be a thing, I want to be able to have more options from the default position. I already tried to change the plugin to: `yearRange:"c-20:c+20"` but it did not work, it kept the -10+10 pagination. I already also tried the following solution:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  yearRange: "2002:2012"
});
```

Which will work but with years limitation which is not exactly what I am looking for? I already tried the following one:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(1990, 1 - 1, 1)
});
```

But also did not work, the behavior was still `c-10:c+10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set the range different than -10 or +10 from today's date, right?

Since that option takes a string, you can build one to create your custom range:

```
var earliest_date = new Date().getFullYear() - 20;
var latest_date = new Date().getFullYear() + 20;

// date_range will be 1997:2037
var date_range = earliest_date + ':' + latest_date;

$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  yearRange: date_range
});
```

Hopefully this helps!

**Update:**

I noticed in the jsFiddle, the pagination behaves as expected, preventing the user from going past Dec 2037 or prior to Jan 1997, yet the user can still manually type any date into the input.

To stop this, you'll want to set `minDate` and `maxDate` instead of `yearRange`.

```
var earliest_date = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 20))
var latest_date = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 20))

//var date_range = earliest_date + ':' + latest_date;

$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  minDate: earliest_date, 
  maxDate: latest_date
});
```

[I've updated the jsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lju82dvu/1/)

Comment: that is not the perfect solution but is the solution I also thought that could do the trick and that I started to implement. i will accept your answer

Comment: Thanks, see my updated answer though, it may be more appropriate than the one I initially posted.

Comment: that solution does not work with my calendar... the problem with my calendar is you can select a year for example I want to set my birthday to 12-09-1950. When I open the calendar with your solution the years that I will see will be the range -10,+10 and I need to load the rest because they won't be loaded from the start. yearRange does that, the problem is to add the limit for todays date in yearRange for instance.

Comment: if you add:   changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true to your datepicker, you will see what I mean

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want to allow the picker to go backwards say, 20 years, but not let it go forward past today's date? If so, check out the jsFiddle, I've updated it with the options you said to include, as well as a maxDate of todays date, to prevent it from going forward: https://jsfiddle.net/Lju82dvu/5/